# Consolibyte Quickbooks Connection Problem

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm trying to connect my website (in Developer Mode, so Sandbox True, non https) to Intuit from the Consolibyte "docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php" file, but I keep getting the following error:

> Uh oh, there’s a connection problem. Sorry, but the app didn’t
>   connect. Please try again later, or contact customer support for help.
>
> View error details (for Developers) The redirect_uri query parameter
>   value is invalid. Make sure it is listed in the Redirect URIs section
>   on your app's keys tab and matches it exactly. Click here to learn
>   more about the redirect_uri query parameter.

I've set the Redirect Uri in my intuit developer account for this app to the same Return URL in the Consolibyte config.php (docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php), but it still isn't working.

Am I doing something wrong? I followed everything in the quick start guide correctly.

config.php code:

```
$oauth_client_id = '***';
$oauth_client_secret = '***';

// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
//$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens

// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://www.***.com/quickbooks/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://www.***.com/quickbooks/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';

// This is the menu URL script
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://www.***.com/quickbooks/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';

// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
$dsn = 'mysqli://***_intuit:***@localhost/***_quickbooks';

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = '***';

// Scope required
$scope = 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting ';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant sections of `config.php`, and a screenshot of Intuit's developer portal, so that we can make sure it matches? Intuit obviously doesn't think it matches...

Comment: https://ibb.co/XyxZY7g
https://ibb.co/x63MxR1

Comment: 1. Post the rest of the relevant `config_oauthv2.php` file - _all_ of the URLs. That URL doesn't even matter. 
2. Update your original post with this information.
3. Don't screenshot code. It's text. Copy/paste.

Comment: I added the code to my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect URL doesn't match.

- In Intuit's control panel it ends with `success.php`.
- In your configuration, it ends with `oauth.php`.

The two URLs *have to match exactly*.

Also, make sure you're using the latest code from https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php - if you're using the latest code, you should have a `config_oauthv2.php` file and not just `config.php`.

Comment: Works now. I changed it from success to oauth and it works :) Thanks!